# Convert millisecond unix to date in laravel

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I am receiving milliseconds UNIX timestamp from google and I need to convert them into actual date (not date time just date).

**How can I do that with carbon?**

*all my search results ware **datetime to milliseconds** instead of **milliseconds to date**.*

`sample of data i receive:`

```
"startTimeMillis" => "1580000000000",
"expiryTimeMillis" => "1580000000000",
```

I need to convert these to dates like `2020-06-26`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use function `createFromTimestampMs`

and return with format you need `format()`

```
$millesecondsTimestamp = 1691915427814;
$date = Carbon::createFromTimestampMs($millesecondsTimestamp);
return $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: because question being duplicate !

Comment: @mafortis I think maybe millesecond time it`s very important for you, and you text that you need do this in with Carbon, check docs good luck!

https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/